# Why can't my Linux shell program sometimes find a file it just created?

Tags: linux, shell, file, cron, sh

I have written a Linux shell program to keep my server information updated. It works by creating a new file with the newest server information and comparing it with the old one. However, the program sometimes can't find the new file.

```
now=$(cd $(dirname $0);pwd)
while [ ! -s "$now/../var/service.info.temp" ];do
    sh "$now/get_service_info.sh" > "$now/../var/service.info.temp"
done
diff "$now/../var/service.info.temp" "$now/../var/service.info" >> "$now/../var/update.log" 2>> "$now/../var/update.log"
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    sh "$now/send_service_info.sh" >> "$now/../var/update.log" 2>> "$now/../var/update.log"
    cp "$now/../var/service.info.temp" "$now/../var/service.info"
fi
rm "$now/../var/service.info.temp"
```

What I found in `update.log` (`cat` is called in `send_service_info.sh`):

```
diff: /home/(my user name)/network/sh/../var/service.info.temp: No such file or directory
cat: /home/(my user name)/network/sh/../var/service.info.temp: No such file or directory
```

The program is run per minute by cron:

```
# one line of my crontab
* * * * * sh /home/(my user name)/network/sh/check_update.sh
```

I have run the program by hand many times, but it never throws the error above when I do that. I only found it through the log and wrongly sent emails. The problem does not happen every time, it only happens every 20 minutes to one hour one time when run by cron.

The `while` loop in the program is newly added to overcome the file problem, but it doesn't work. I still get the same result. I also tried manufacturing delay in `get_service_info.sh` (by `sleep 5s`) but it still runs well when I run it by hand. I have simplified `get_servive_info.sh` to only one command `hostname -I`, but the problem persists.

My Linux system is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Linux 4.14.141+) run by UserLand on an Android mobile phone (has not been rooted). I use `ssh` to connect to it and do my work. I also find my system will be paused if the screen is off between 0 AM and 6 AM, which may link to the problem above (in both cases the `cron` is unresponsive).

According to suggestions, I have changed the program code to:

```
set -e

now=$(cd $(dirname $0);pwd)
get="$now/get_service_info.sh"
send="$now/send_service_info.sh"
var="$now/../var"
log="$var/update.log"
origin="$var/service.info"
temp="$var/service.info.temp.$$"

exec >> $log 2>> $log

while [ ! -s $temp ];do
    sh $get > $temp
done
if [[ $(diff $origin $temp) ]];then
    sh $send
    cp $temp $origin
fi
rm $temp
```

I think I have waited for enough time and it does not throw an error again. That is because of the long execution time. I ignore this because when I test it with an SSH connection, it only takes less than 1 second for that program. Maybe my system will become much slower when it runs automatically, because of the battery-saving mode or some other things. Finally, for readability and robustness here is the code after the change:

```
set -e

now=$(cd $(dirname $0);pwd)
get="$now/get_service_info.sh"
send="$now/send_service_info.sh"
var="$now/../var"
log="$var/update.log"
origin="$var/service.info"
temp="$var/service.info.temp.$$"

exec >> "$log" 2>> "$log"

while ! test -s "$temp" ; do
    sh "$get" > "$temp"
done
if ! diff -q "$origin" "$temp" > /dev/null ; then
    sh "$send" "$temp"
    cp "$temp" "$origin"
fi
rm "$temp"
```

Comment: Tagentially [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Linux 4.14.141+) run by UserLand on an Android mobile phone (has not been rooted). I use ssh to connect to it and do my work` wow. Do you work on it like on a pc? The script "looks fine". You could do `exec 2>"$now/../var/update.log"` instead of redirecting each command. I think environment - that it is an android phone - might be worth researching. The error might come from concurrent execution - add `flock`. Running it every minute, how long does a single execution take? You might also want to add `set -xe`, or rewrite it in like python to handle errors differently.

Comment: It's surprising it does anything with all those long, repeated paths everywhere. If something is going to appear more than once in a script, make a sensible short variable name for it at the start then use that variable throughout. It's easier to type, easier to read and easier to maintain.

Comment: `if [[ $(diff $origin $temp) ]];then` should be simply `if ! diff -q "$origin" "$temp" >/dev/null`. Maybe read the antipattern question I linked to again. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: It's probably not useful to go back and update this question any longer, but in the future, please don't add answers to your question. Feel free to post an answer of your own down on the page using the "Post Your Answer" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script takes for whatever reason approximately 1 minute to execute, you have a race condition: A new process will started by cron before the old one is finished, and then the `rm` old process removes the  file perhaps just before the `diff` of the new process gets executed.

I suggest that you create a process-specific temp file:

```
service_info_temp=$now/../var/service.info.temp.$$
while [ ! -s "$service_info_temp" ]
do
  ....
```

Comment: The predictable temporary name is a bit of a glitch; properly speaking you want to use a secure temporary file, using `mktemp` etc.

Comment: @tripleee: I was thinking of it, but with the current scenario, I could not think of a scenario where the use of `$$` would exhibit a serious risk. What I certainly would do, however, is to establish a `trap` which ensures that the temp file is going to be deleted, even if the scripts aborts for whatever reason.

Comment: Another solution would be to attempt to create a new directory with a static name, and abort the run if the directory already exists. But then you need so be really sure that the process which grabs the lock directory is also guaranteed to remove it when it's done, even if it crashes or etc.